# Understanding unusable documentation of reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I needed to get scroll position of div, so I found `onScroll` event in react documentation, use it in my code and in developer tool found properties that I needed.
In documentation I found some words:

```
Event names:

onScroll

Properties:

number detail
DOMAbstractView view
```

Many times I come across a situation when I do not understand why something is written in the documentation and how to use it.
Could someone help me and explain what this documentation is saying?

Answer (score 2):

What the documentation is saying is that if you capture the `onScroll` event, that event object will have at least two properties, including `detail` and `view`. For example, this means that you can do:

```
function onScrollHandler(event) {
  console.log(event);
  console.log(event.detail);
  console.log(event.view);
}
```

Specifically, `detail` will be of type `number` and `view` will be of type `DOMAbstractView`

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand yet what does property detail means? I'm trying console.log(event.detail) and getting 0 every time. And one more thing - event object have a lot of other properties. For me it's strange -  mention about two properties and tell anything about others.

Comment: Yes, `0` is a number, and as the docs say, `event.detail` is of type number. What exactly that number means I don't know - link to the docs and maybe I can find it there. And as I said, `events` has lots of things, and all the docs are saying is that `event` will have at a minimum the `detail` and `view` attributes. The `event` itself is a complicated thing, giving you lots of information about the event. Go learn about [DOM events](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) to see what you can do with them.

Comment: So, [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) explains the base fields of the event. As you can see, the spec shows that `event.detail` will **always** be `0`. It seems to me that the `event.detail` property actually comes from the [mouse event category](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_detail.asp), which kind of makes sense if you think of a scroll event being an extension of the mouse event, but you don't click to do a scroll so the number of clicks is always 0.